# How can we retrieve an interface from the base class and test it?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, superclass

*Unit Testing inquiry*

I have to test the functionality of several classes, handled via their `superclass`.

I.e.: We have a custom class `CustomerInitialiserImpl` that extends `SpAsyncHandler`, which latter has the following method: `protected executeAsync(ExecuteAsync executeAsync)` (The parameter `ExecuteAsync` is an interface and what the method `executeAsync`, does is run the interface methods in a specific order within one or more async threads).

`ExecuteAsync` looks like the following:

```
public interface ExecuteAsync {
       void initApi();
       void doInBackground();
       void onPostExecute();
}
```

`CustomerInitialiserImpl` has the following method:

```
public void initialiseCustomer(int id) {
       executeAsync(new ExeuteAsync() {
/*here are instantiated the 3 overridden methods of the interface*/
       });
}
```

Since I don't care about the Async work done in `SpAsyncHandler`, it has its own tests, I need, however, to test if the methods of the interface are executed correctly and whether they trigger the expected outcome (f.i. the correct `post` events via `EventBus`, etc).

I've been trying to find a way to grab those instantiated interfaces on my test class, but I can't seem to find a way around it.

I have tried using `PowerMockito` to grab the `protected` method and see if I can return the `interface`, but I haven't succeeded.

Also, this interface includes the instantiation of some specific `api` methods that are to be mocked. Any clues on how can I proceed and if this can be done? I know the architecture doesn't sound ideal. How can I proceed?

Comment: Options include testing the externally visible behavior of `initializeCustomer()`, or extracting a named class from the anonymous class, and testing its methods individually on an instance.

Comment: What troubles me is that there are dozens of classes that inherit and use the `SpAsyncHandler`, and each of these classes may hold up to several uses of the `executeAsync(ExecuteAsync executeAsync)`. Basically, the classes that extend it are usually filled with methods invoking it.

Comment: I think the unit test/s to insure that the `ExecuteAsync` methods are called correctly are those for `executeAsync()`, and don't depend on the number of concrete implementations. For the unit tests for behavior of the n implementations, you might find it helpful to write a helper test method that accepts an `ExecuteAsync` and performs the desired tests. Then, you can call that for each instance. Optionally, you could use parameterized tests, available in both junit and testng.

Comment: Basically I am concerned only about the n implementations of `ExecuteAsync`. If I want to execute an instance of `CustomerInitialiser.initialiseCustomer(int id)`, the problem would be that 1) the interface is initialised therein, 2) the method invokes `executeAsync()`, which would break (we can't get there in testing). One idea I just had to fix this would be to make a decent refactoring and from `initialiseCustomer()` to invoke `executeAsync(() -> asyncInitCustomer())` and place/test the business logic within the `asyncInitCustomer()`.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out, but had to convert to Kotlin first.

I used Kotlin's delegation, so that `CustomerInitialiserImpl` would implement the interface of the `SpAsyncHandler`, which would usually inject the normal `SpAsyncHandlerImpl`, however in the Unit Tests, I would set the delegation via `MockSpAsyncHandlerImpl`, that would, among other things, just execute all interface functions on the main thread. Passing on mocked objects, it works like a charm!